# Adding image from web blocking jpeg

Tags: support

I wanted to add an image to a post, I chose the "provide a link from the web" option, and it gave me "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported". That would make sense if I was trying to upload some strange format, but it was just a plain old `jpeg`, namely "http://taniwha.web.fc2.com/MTG_image/FE/FE_Img/FE_B3.jpg". Can you seriously not link to jpegs? Or, is there something wrong with that particular image?

Answer (score 2):

That URL redirects to a regular HTML webpage, and just happens to have `.jpg` at the end. If you want the URL for the actual image, right click the image and choose "Copy image address". That will give you the URL for the actual image.

Comment: The actual URL for the image ***is*** the URL that gets redirected to a HTML page though. (Until caching magic happens in your browser, which will probably be after the first time you visit that URL. But the image uploader might not be doing that caching magic.)

Comment: When I open the image URL, I see query parameters that make it serve an image instead of the webpage.

Comment: Oh, right!! The `?50160067` on the end of `http://taniwha.web.fc2.com/MTG_image/FE/FE_Img/FE_B3.jpg?50160067` makes it reliably point to the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with that particular URL (not the image itself), because when I open it, I get redirected to a HTML page which, in turn, provides an image file. Web servers can do that kind of thing, for reasons such as hotlink protection.

The  image uploader would *also* get redirected to a HTML page and say "welp, I can't do HTML pages" and give up.

You should save that file to your computer and try to upload it from there.